# "The term 'New-Mailbox' is not recognized" error given from c# application

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2010

I have an application on a Windows 2012 server running Exchange 2010. Code is below:

```
string scriptpath = @"c:\scripts\emailtooltest.ps1";

        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command execPS = new Command(scriptpath);
        pipeline.Commands.Add(execPS);
        var results = pipeline.Invoke();

        Console.Read();
```

I can execute manually when executing as administrator, but when attempting to execute through the application this exception is returned: "*The term 'New-Mailbox' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.*" I think this is a permissions issue, and I everything I've researched seems to reference snapins, but those seem to be exclusive to Exchange 2007. Am I confused? Any ideas?

Comment: You need to create an outlook account on the PC for the user that is running.  I would open outlook up manually and let it automatically create an account.  Then try you code again.

Comment: This isn't desirable as the application is controlled by a webpage. I don't think it's feasible to have an account created for every user.

Comment: Your application needs two piece of information.  1) Were the user mailbox is located. 2) The users credentials.  When you create an outlook account locally on the PC both pieces of information is created.  When you logon without a local account you need to use an Outlook Web Application.